# Fire certain method after every action in Web APi

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I'm writting a ASP.NET WEB API.

Once the Action is executed i want to call a method.

For example:

```
 public string Action1(object a)
 {
     // ...
     // call method1();
     return "sample1";
 }

 public string Action2(object b)
 {
     // ...
     // call method1();
     return "sample2";
 }
```

Is there a way to call `method1()` on every action without mentioning in every action?

Answer (score 10):

You can implement an custom `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute` and call `method1()` inside `OnActionExecuted(...)`:

```
public class MyActionFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        // call method1();
        // ...
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

You can then use this `[MyActionFilter]` on the action, on the controller, or add it to the global config in `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
        config.Filters.Add(new MyActionFilter());
```

Comment: I guess the OP wants to execute a piece of code after the action is executed. So, `OnActionExecuted` method of `ActionFilterAttribute` would be better fit here.

Comment: @tugberk - thx for the correction.  I have updated my answer accordingly.